# Can Jenkins return 0 and 1 after test suites completed?

Tags: jenkins

My query is related to Jenkins server.
I have made one API to hit the Jenkins server where Jenkins starts test suites.

My question is: can Jenkins server return 0 if any test case fail, and 1 otherwise?

The API URL is in the form

```
JENKINS_URL/job/Encore_Automation/build?token=TOKEN_NAME
```

Answer (score 1):

By looking at `Build Triggers / Trigger builds remotely (e.g., from scripts)` it seems like this option only supports queuing a project and it does not let you retrieve results.

## Jenkins REST API

After build has been triggered from REST API call, you could start making consecutive REST API calls to check it status.

## Jenkins CLI

However Jenkins offers a [`jenkins-cli`](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+CLI) tool which let you not only to trigger the build but also to wait until its completion:

```
java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://localhost:8080/ build JOB [-c] [-f] [-p] [-r N] [-s] [-v] [-w]
Starts a build, and optionally waits for a completion.
Aside from general scripting use, this command can be
used to invoke another job from within a build of one job.
With the -s option, this command changes the exit code based on
the outcome of the build (exit code 0 indicates a success)
and interrupting the command will interrupt the job.
With the -f option, this command changes the exit code based on
the outcome of the build (exit code 0 indicates a success)
however, unlike -s, interrupting the command will not interrupt
the job (exit code 125 indicates the command was interrupted).
With the -c option, a build will only run if there has been
an SCM change.

 JOB : Name of the job to build
 -c  : Check for SCM changes before starting the build, and if there's no
       change, exit without doing a build
 -f  : Follow the build progress. Like -s only interrupts are not passed
       through to the build.
 -p  : Specify the build parameters in the key=value format.
 -s  : Wait until the completion/abortion of the command. Interrupts are passed
       through to the build.
 -v  : Prints out the console output of the build. Use with -s
 -w  : Wait until the start of the command
```

Comment: Is there any other way to do same steps???like if i don't want to install and add jenkins-cli tool